# Global height data as polygons — Natural Earth doesn't have it?

Tags: shapefile, data, elevation, natural-earth

I love the bathymetry data from Natural Earth. I've been looking for the last few days for the same basic data but for land. I'm trying to find *general* elevation shapefiles, as polygons. I don't need it to be 100% accurate since it's just for appearance of a stylised map.

Unable to find it, I've been trying to make it in QGIS. I've managed to convert global heightmap data to a shapefile, but it came out as squares matching pixels. That's no good. Trying to convert contours to polygons doesn't work, obviously,

Is there a place to download elevation shapefiles equivalent to the Natural Earth equivalent bathymetry?

Why is it so hard to find lower resolution elevation data that's global?

Comment: Interesting question - there is a discussion of the method for creating these nested elevation polygons [here](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_SolutionCenter/gw_create_contour_polygons.htm). I think most of the tools they mention have a GRASS equivalent.

Comment: Interesting. I was surprised when I wasn't able to find the shapefiles as polygons since they exist for what's below sea level, and it seems like there'd be the same issues between the two.

Comment: I assume though that bathymetric data is whole lot more sparse than elevation data, and thus more suited to conversion to polygon.  I think in the main you will need to get hold of some free raster data, such as SRTM (http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/) and do the conversion yourself for the areas you are interested in.